# set my model with viewbag value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5

Within a form I populate my output model (that will be handled by the controller).
One value is not a user input, it is actually an object from previous page I injected with Viewbag to this page.
Now I want to set this object to one of my model properties (complex object) and I'm looking for a way to do it.
I encountered

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m =>
```

But I can't seem to understand how to set my propery there

Comment: How you will use it in current form

Comment: well I actually just present some fields from this object, but I need to move this forward but this time as a member of the output model of the page

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You can not use `HiddenFor` without using a model.

You can try,

```
@Html.Hidden("FieldId", ViewBag.FieldId)
```

Access it in controller like

```
public ActionResult Action(string FieldId)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I already have model that is being populated within the form and handed to the Action. I need the object to be only one of the properties.

Comment: @user1025852, Correct me, In one property of Model passed to view. That will be easy

Answer (score 1):

If the property is available in the `ViewBag` object, then you could do this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new YourViewModelClass();

    viewModel.Property = ViewBag.Property;

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
    // viewModel.Property will contain the hidden input value.
}
```

**View**

`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property);`

This way, you keep the value from the `ViewBag` inside your viewmodel when it is posted back to the server.

Comment: what is YouViewModelClass? is it Myview.cshtml?

Comment: That's a made up class name. You mentioned that you had a model, just use your model instead of `YourViewModel`.